# Update and Replace Values in one Table Column with Values from another Table Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables:

```
id | bsi | cell 

1  | 45 | NULL
2  | 23 | 600-1167
3  | 47 | 
4  | 89 | 501- -
5  | 98 | 603-5670
```

I would like to replace cell values with data from another colum in another table matching both tables by bsi

Here is my 2nd table:

```
id | bsi | contact 

1  | 45 | 610-5896 
2  | 23 | 605-4567 
3  | 47 | NULL 
4  | 89 | 689-9089
5  | 98 | NULL
```

I would like each value in the first table replaced with the new value in 2nd table also the value where both tables match in bsi code ie to replace the NULL and '501- -' with the new value once there is one in the 2nd table.

So result should be an updated table as follows:

```
id | bsi | cell 

1  | 45 | 610-5896
2  | 23 | 605-4567
3  | 47 | NULL
4  | 89 | 689-9089
5  | 98 | 603-5670
```

I have tried this query but it only replaces the new values and seems to write null values for items that are in table1 and not table2. I want to keep the table1 values that are in table 1 but not table 2.

```
UPDATE Table1 
   SET Table1.cell = Table2.Contact
   FROM Table1  INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table1.bsi = Table2.bsi
```

Answer (score 1):

Your join seems to be a little off... you aren't joining the second table

```
UPDATE t1
   SET t1.cell = t2.Contact
   FROM Table1  t1
   INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON           --changed to table2
   t1.bsi = t2.bsi 
   --where <some condition>
```

Also, it can be faster to just update all rows than to be selective using a `where clause`. [See Aaron Bertrand's tests on this.](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/conditional-updates) I did it this way because despite you stating that *I want to keep the table1 values that are in table 1 but not table 2*, this wasn't reflected in your expected output. If you really do want to conditionally update them, then you need to add the `where clause`.

[SEE DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1e47022b3dbce524a6731a2bdc6eb914)

```
create table table1 (id int, bsi int, cell varchar(16))

create table table2 (id int, bsi int, contact varchar(16))

insert into table1 values
(1,45,NULL),
(2,23,'600-1167'),
(3,47,''), 
(4,89,'501- -')

insert into table2 values
(1,45,'610-5896'), 
(2,23,'605-4567'), 
(3,47,NULL), 
(4,89,'689-9089')

UPDATE t1
   SET t1.cell = t2.Contact
   FROM Table1  t1
   INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON           --changed to table2
   t1.bsi = t2.bsi 
   --where <some condition>


select * from table1
```

**RETURNS**

```
+----+-----+----------+
| id | bsi |   cell   |
+----+-----+----------+
|  1 |  45 | 610-5896 |
|  2 |  23 | 605-4567 |
|  3 |  47 |          |
|  4 |  89 | 689-908  |
+----+-----+----------+
```

Comment: I tried this and it replaces my values in table 1 with NULL

Comment: If I add  where  t1.cell <>  t2.Contact it only replaces the values where there isnt a match

Comment: Here is a demo https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1e47022b3dbce524a6731a2bdc6eb914 with your exact data

Comment: @scsimon There is something missing there. It could be the sample data or the OP want something else and can't explain well.

Comment: I don't see how @Sami my code produces the [expected results](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1e47022b3dbce524a6731a2bdc6eb914) in the OP with the sample data supplied. But who knows lol

Comment: I changed the expected output

Comment: @scsimon I can't even understand what he want exactly

Comment: Now your expected output makes no sense. You changed the value of bsi = 23 but didn't for bsi = 98. There no real logic here @ivias and why dind't bsi=59 stay the same? Because it wasn't a full number? Your sample data is awful now.

Comment: BSI 98 is null in 2nd table so we need to keep value in 1st table which is 603-5670

Comment: 47 is null in second table but blank in 1st table and yet, you took the null value. Just add `where t2.contact is not null` at the bottom of the update. *Maybe* that is what you want

Comment: Okay this seems to have worked for the condition:  WHERE t1.cell IS NULL OR t1.cell <> t2.Contact

Comment: That is a longer way to write the same thing, yes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your query was joining back on itself. Change the table you are joining on to be Table2 instead.

This will update only rows in Table1 that match up with rows in Table2 by the bsi value, setting the cell value to Contact

UPDATE Table1 
       SET Table1.cell = Table2.Contact
       FROM Table1
             INNER JOIN Table2
       ON Table1.bsi = Table2.bsi